# Developer Console content rating error

Tags: android, google-play

I have built an app and publish it on Google Play in Developer Console.
I was asked for select content rating, and the `Everyone` option was disabled and I got an error:

> Some rating options have been disabled based on the content of your application

My application is only simple tool that control the WiFi adapter (show statistics and control it). So I dont know why the Developer Console deside that my app can't be published for everyone.

Is there any way how to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide the list of permissions your App is using?

Comment: Agreed, my guess is that you are have a permission in your AndroidManifest.xml (please post it if possible) that is causing your issue.

Comment: I have given list of permission in my app `<uses-permission android:name="com.shopclues.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />`current maturity level is `medium` on play store and maturity level `low` and `everyone` are disable. please suggest me due to which permission not able to select `low` and `everyone`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Play Market Guidelines for the 'Everyone' Rating:

```
Everyone

    Applications in this category should not collect user’s location data or contain objectionable material. Applications should not share user content or include social features.
```

Do you have social features, or are you recording location data, or other data?

Double check the permissions you are requesting in your AndroidManifest.xml, as I expect the store is finding something in your app that enables location, or other data sharing (maybe you have READ_CONTACT, or another similar permission).

You can get details on the ratings at the following URL: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1075738?hl=en

Comment: Yea I have social features. I didn't see this in the guidelines... Where did you found it? Should I need to set it to `Low Maturity`?

Comment: Read the guidelines (I included link in original answer), and don't forget to mark this answer as correct.  Looks to me like you should choose 'Medium Maturity', but I don't know your app specifics.

Comment: Actually, the information available in the referred link is incomplete. Which specific permissions increase the content rating to which level?

Comment: In the email Google will send you has a link to appeal the decision. Click the link and fill in all the info asked for. They will get back to you with in 72 hours.